# ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘ENMTools’

Tags: r, linux

I am trying to install ENMtools in R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Linux Mint 20.1

But get the following error:

installing to /home/alonso/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/00LOCK-rgeos/00new/rgeos/libs
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
** checking absolute paths in shared objects and dynamic libraries
** testing if installed package can be loaded from final location
** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path

- DONE (rgeos)
- installing *source* package ‘ENMTools’ ...
  ** package ‘ENMTools’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
  ** using staged installation
  ** R
  ** data
  *** moving datasets to lazyload DB
  ** inst
  ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
  double free or corruption (!prev)
  Aborted (core dumped)
  ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘ENMTools’
- removing ‘/home/XXX/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/ENMTools’
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ENMTools’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
‘/tmp/RtmpWvRhkI/downloaded_packages’

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: You could try to install the package with no lock option, i.e. `install.packages("ENMTools", dependencies = TRUE, INSTALL_opts = '--no-lock')`.

Comment: Dear @tacoman thanks for your suggestion. Ran it twice with no success. There are some dependencies that cannot be install.